# Android: Infinitely running Service for receiving events?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a requirement that my app, can receive events (e.g. messages) from server any time (even if app is not running). So do I need to create an infinitely running service to listen for these events?

This to me seems similar to Email apps in Smartphones, like whenever you receive a new email(event in my case), its able to show notifications and also able to update my list adapter whenever I receive an event.

But I dun know how will I implement this?

Comment: It is impossible to create an "infinitely running service". The user and the OS will get rid of your service eventually. Please use C2DM, or rewrite your app to remove the "requirement" (e.g., check for messages every N minutes using `AlarmManager`, where N is something that can be controlled by the user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at C2DM (push-messages):
http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/android/c2dm/index.html#intro
it allows a server to send messages to devices at any time.

From the link:

> Here are the primary characteristics of Android Cloud to Device
>   Messaging (C2DM):
>
> It allows third-party application servers to send lightweight messages to their Android applications. The messaging service is not
>   designed for sending a lot of user content via the messages. Rather,
>   it should be used to tell the application that there is new data on
>   the server, so that the application can fetch it.
>   [...]
>   An application on an Android device doesn’t need to be running to
>   receive messages. The system will wake up the application via Intent
>   broadcast when the the message arrives, as long as the application is
>   set up with the proper broadcast receiver and permissions.
>   [...]

Answer (score 0):

Events from server are called "push notifications" and are implemented via "Cloud 2 device messaging" (C2DM). On the mobile side these messages are submitted as broadcast events (see `BroadcastReceiver`). For a complete example see some tutorials: [Google](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/c2dm/), [Vogella](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) or here on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+c2dm)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to start a `Service` as soon as the device booted. There is a good tutorial [here](http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/82) how to achieve this.